# Line chart with partially filled area

Tags: javascript, svg, chartist.js

I use a line chart of [Chartist.js](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html) and want it to be filled but only on the left side up to a certain value on the X axis.

My idea was to use two different data series, one filled, the other not. This works quite well, only on the junction it is bended.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="chart-comparison" class="ct-chart ct-golden-section"></div>
```

And here the JS:

```
new Chartist.Line('#chart-comparison', {
  labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'series-1',
      data: [0, 2, 4, 5]
    },
    [null, null, null, 5, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1, 0]
  ]
}, {
  fullWidth: true,
  showPoint: false,
  series: { 'series-1': { showArea: true }},
  axisY: { onlyInteger: true }
});
```

To look and try I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81z7s7tr/1/) as well

What I would *like* to have is a single series, but with only a percentage of the area marked:

```
new Chartist.Line('#chart-comparison', {
  labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'series-1',
      data: [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1, 0]
    }
  ]
}, {
  fullWidth: true,
  showPoint: false,
  series: { 'series-1': {
    showArea: true,
    markOnly: '56%'     // <---- This is an undefined attribute which I would like to use
  }},
  axisY: { onlyInteger: true }
});
```

I've already tried to clip the area by altering the svg dynamically, but it is recreated on window resize, so this is not really an option.

Does anyone here has an idea what to do?

Comment: Any chance you could rerun the clipping code on the window resize event? (That's my only other thought after trying to look for a solution or workaround that you haven't already come up with yourself.)

Comment: Yes, I think that would work. In fact, this is the core of my own solution I worked on in the mean time: I created a plugin. For documentation, I will add an answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I created a plugin for Chartist.js that adds a clipping path to the svg.

https://github.com/jschirrmacher/chartist-plugin-partialarea